# list spiders from scrapy shell and run individual spider

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I want to access scrapy shell from within "scrapy project folder" in terminal. And want to list all the available spiders in my project. I also like to run individual spider and play with the response.

Once i enter into scrapy shell i get following object:

```
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10b75cbd0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10cba1b90>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

My best guess is, i use methods from "crawler" object to list available spider. But i have no luck. Also please do let me know how to run spider once i list it.

Answer (score 0):

> list all the available spiders in my project

Use `crawler.spiders.list()`:

```
>>> for spider_name in crawler.spiders.list():
...     print(spider_name)
```

Comment: It showed the spider list but how do you run individual spider now from the shell itself? 
Eg: if i want to get the response from first spider and play with response and again later in time if i wish to crawl different spider to get its response how do i do it?